# Jupyter-lab not found

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm on macOS Big Sur, running python3.9 installed with homebrew. I had some path link problem with my old jupyter so I uninstalled it. I couldn't remember how I installed the jupyter in the past so I manually rm jupyter files in /usr/local/bin and /usr/local/Cellar.

Then I reinstalled jupyter-lab using pip3 install. Then when I run `jupyter lab`, it gave me traceback:

```
File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyter_core/command.py", line 285, in main
    command = _jupyter_abspath(subcommand)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyter_core/command.py", line 124, in _jupyter_abspath
    raise Exception(
Exception: Jupyter command `jupyter-lab` not found.
```

However, I've checked the jupyter notebook command. It worked fine. It seems I'm only missing the jupyter-lab file. What should I do?

Comment: Did you use `python -m pip install jupyter-lab`, or `pip install jupyter lab`?  I came across this problem too, and I used `python -m pip install jupyterlab` without the dash or any spaces (the spaces might make it think you're trying to install two different packages), and it worked just fine.

Comment: I used `pip3 install jupyterlab`.

Comment: Did the latter command work?

Comment: I ran the later command just now and it shows all "requirements already satisfied". I think `python -m pip install jupyterlab` is the same as `pip3 install jupyterlab`

Comment: Please add the result of your `jupyter server extension list` to the question.

Comment: `Config dir: /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/etc/jupyter

Config dir: /usr/local/etc/jupyter
    jupyterlab enabled
    - Validating jupyterlab...
      jupyterlab 3.0.6 OK
    nbclassic enabled
    - Validating nbclassic...
      nbclassic  OK` @krassowski

Answer (score 1):

Did you add /.local/bin to the environment path?

`export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin`

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.